# jdom performance

Tags: java, xml, performance, xml-parsing, jdom

I am currently using native Java XML processing library (Xerces). I can't use any sax parser because I need random access to xml nodes. I am finding that CPU usage goes 100% when I am parsing XML files. There are large number of small size (1-10kb) that I am processing like this-

```
while(hasFile){
processXMlfile(hasFile.next);
}
```

In processXMlfile() I am building parsing and processing file.

If I move to JDOM library, will I gain any performance benefit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottleneck is probably XML parsing, and JDOM will likely use the same XML parser under the covers, so it won't make any difference.

A key factor when you are parsing lots of small files is to avoid the parser initialization costs. Reuse the same XML parser instance for all the files.

Comment: Thanks Michael. After re-using instances, though CPU usage does remain @ 100%, throughput has vastly improved (from about 40-50 files to about 200 files)

Comment: cpu usage of 100% is surely a good thing, why would you want less?

Comment: I won't...sometimes system admins don't see it as a good thing. For them its a red flag situation

Comment: If you want CPU usage of less than 100% you will have to arrange to do more I/O. It will slow the system down, but if you want to make a fool of your system admins, go ahead and do it.

Answer (score 5):

JDOM 2.0.0 addresses a number of performance issues. One of them is directly related to the 'tight loop' processing of XML files.

Have a look at:

http://hunterhacker.github.com/jdom/jdom2/apidocs/org/jdom2/input/sax/package-summary.html

You should do something like:

```
SAXBuilder saxbuilder = new SAXBuilder();
saxbuilder.setVariousConfigurations()
SAXEngine saxengine = saxbuilder.buildEnine();

while(hasfile) {
  processXML(saxengine, nextfile);
}
```

Using the SAXEngine concept in JDOM 2.0.0 will completely eliminate the setup of the SAX-parsing infrastructure. That setup time accounts for a huge proprotion of overall procesing.

While you may still be running at 100%, yu will find your throughput will likely more than double....