# Reduce overhead of creating JDOM objects

Tags: java, xpath, web-crawler, jdom

I am working on a project that evaluates web pages on a large scale (millions). Unlike the typical web crawler, my evaluator needs to build a `JDOM` object for each page it evaluates in order to run `XPath` queries on it.

Our current implementation uses `SAXBuilder` to instantiate JDOM objects (some are then cached for potential future use) in order to query XPaths. But simple profiling shows that the instantiation process actually consumes the most time, much more than querying XPaths and so I am left looking for alternative solutions. Is there any way to reduce this overhead by for example:

1. Creating "lean" JDOM objects with only minimal structural information of the page?
2. Evaluating XPaths without an actual JDOM object?
3. Initialising JDOM objects faster by re-using the object for a "similar" page?

EDIT:
We are using `JDOM` 2.X.

A sample of the way we initialize a `JDOM` object:

```
public static List<Element> evaluateHTML(File html, String pattern) throws JDOMException, IOException {
    Element page = saxBuilder.build(html).getRootElement();
    XPathBuilder xpath = new XPathBuilder(pattern, Filters.element());
    //...set xpath namespaces...
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compileWith(xpathFactory);
    return expr.evaluate(page);
}
```

Where `xpathFactory` is a static member and `evaluateHTML` is invoked for every html file we evaluate.

Comment: +1 Good question. Can you show us a bit of code showing how you instantiate the JDOM objects? That will help narrow down the possible answers.

Comment: Also, are you using JDOM 1.x or 2.x? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16316589/423105 for example.

Comment: See also the two answers under http://stackoverflow.com/q/10116891/423105